# SpeechNavigation option. What is it for?

Tags: options

Could somebody please explain what is the use for `SpeechNavigation` option found in the option inspector?

Comment: From [way back in 2008](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Nov/msg00003.html): "Really nobody knows what the option SpeechNavigation stands for?
Not even people at WRI?"

Comment: @blochwave :-) yeah, I asked this in 2008 in MathGroup. Perhaps this time someone will reply.

Answer (score 3):

This is what it looks like in the Option Inspector, under Cell Options.

[image: SpeechNavigation in Cell Options]

Given the options available, my guess is that it would be a way of editing the contents of a cell using a microphone (i.e. "Speech Navigation")?

That way the meaning of "Delete", "Paste" and "Select" would be obvious, "Input" and "Output" less clear (perhaps changing the cell type?), and "Motion" might be to move the cursor along a line.

I don't have a microphone to test this hypothesis though.

Comment: I did connect a Mic, changed the settings, spoke into it "Delete" and other stuff, but...nothing :-(